# Url for Remember me Option in Django

Tags: python, django

In my django project i want to use remember me option.Now if user hit `localhost/home` it redirect to home page of that user.If user hit only `localhost/` it is not.

`Localhost/` is the url of my project home page where user can find login and registration.

If already logged in user exist and user hit `localhost/` urlit should take user to `localhost/home`

Comment: Please show your code and ask a specific question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If already logged in user exist and user hit localhost/ urlit should
>   take user to localhost/home

You have to program it.

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/home/')
```